# Execute in Batch not firing:

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have a scheduled batch that I am using to reassign accounts on a weekly basis as they come in. Using Accounts because they typically come in with more than 1 contact and the Leads object is hamstrung on this.

I have 3 classes: the schedule, the batch and the logic.

When I run the schedule nothing happens to the owner ID field. Also - I get none of the debug messages that I expect from the execute - but do from the Start and from the Schedule.
Schedule:

```
global class AccountReassignSchedule implements Schedulable{

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
   AccountReassignSchedule.runBatch();
}

public static void runBatch(){
    string MLCOwnerID;
    list<MLCUser__c> U = MLCUser__c.getall().values();
    if(u.size()>0) {
        MLCOwnerID = u[0].UserID__c;
        System.debug('Sean \n in runBatch() Message follows:' + MLCOwnerID);
        String queryString = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, DoNotAutoReassign__c FROM Account WHERE DoNotAutoReassign__c = false and OwnerId = ' + MLCOwnerID;
        System.debug('Sean \n in runBatch() Message 2 follows:' + queryString);

        //Call the batch
        AccountReassignBatch arBatch = new AccountReassignBatch(queryString);
        Database.executeBatch(arBatch, 100);
    }
}
}
```

Batch:

```
global class AccountReassignBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

global final String query;

global AccountReassignBatch(String q){
    System.debug('Sean \n message in AccoutReassignBatch follows:' + q);
    // here is where the class starts, reassign the local parameter to the global variable
    query = q;
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    // get the data in a single space
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
    //for each object in scope, check the address: the state and the zip, compare that to the available list of zips
    List<Account> acctsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    System.debug('Sean \n message in execute follows:' + acctsToUpdate);
    CheckAddressToReassign CAtR = new CheckAddressToReassign();
    acctsToUpdate = CAtR.checkAddress(scope);
    System.debug('Sean \n message 2 in execute follows:' + scope);
    System.debug('Sean \n message 3 in execute follows:' + acctsToUpdate);
    update acctsToUpdate;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}

}
```

In addition: I am getting a strange log message:

> 09:40:00.0 (7429346)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[19]|this|AccountReassignBatch|true|false
>   09:40:00.0 (7453485)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[19]|this|{"query":"SELECT Id, OwnerId,  (131 more) ..."}|0x46aa752b
>   09:40:00.0 (7459594)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[19]|BC|Database.BatchableContext|true|false
>   09:40:00.0 (7508295)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[19]|BC|{"jobId":"7070v000002EIeiAAG"}|0x15f6a99c
>   09:40:00.0 (7519078)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[19]
>   09:40:00.0 (7520223)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[21]
>   09:40:00.0 (7538996)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
>   09:40:00.0 (7558378)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
>   09:40:00.0 (7565480)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
>   09:40:00.0 (7930818)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[21]|System.QueryException: unexpected token: MvX2
>   09:40:00.0 (7990464)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[21]|Bytes:26
>   09:40:00.0 (8109690)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: unexpected token: MvX2

but this is in a standalone logmessage while a different one seems to indicate that everything is firing. That mvx2 is part of a users ID(15)

Comment: I think your Id need to be surrounded by single quotes. So you need to escape these single quotes using:  `and OwnerId = \'' + MLCOwnerID + '\'';`

Comment: Oh Martin, Thank you... I make "Rookie Mistake" look so endearing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put quotes around the Id:

```
... OwnerId = '\'' + MclOwnerId + '\'';
```

I generally recommend using inline binding:

```
... OwnerId = :MCLOwnerId
```

As well as using inline queries instead of dynamic queries, when possible.

Answer (score 4):

Exception occurs in your scheduled class.

Following similar snippet generates same error:

```
Id ownerId = 'XXXXXX';
String queryString = 'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = ' + ownerId;
System.debug(Database.query(queryString));
```

Try enclosing it in quotes.

Best would be only pass the variable and form your query in execute instead passing whole query.